# Implement Fourier Transform of cross correlation? using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, fft, cross-correlation

I am trying to implement FT of cross correlation to see if the convolution theorem holds true.

I am stuck, because right now my convolution and my fourier transform multiplication are not equal, but they contain the same elements. Just in a different order.

Can somebody help me out? I tried flipping the filter, I tried conjugating it and I tried transposing it.

My inspiration is from https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29761/convolution-theorem-for-cross-correlation

Code

```
conv: tensor([[[[ 0.6908,  1.2291, -0.7020,  1.0186, -1.2585],
          [ 0.3773,  1.8541,  0.8134,  0.2672, -0.5912],
          [ 0.1427,  0.6185,  1.0000, -0.8145, -0.4732],
          [ 1.9047, -0.0119,  0.8849, -1.2321, -0.5614],
          [ 0.0910,  1.0923, -0.6255, -1.9881,  1.9961]]]])
FT result: [[-1.2321 -0.5614  1.9047 -0.0119  0.8849]
 [-1.9881  1.9961  0.091   1.0923 -0.6255]
 [ 1.0186 -1.2585  0.6908  1.2291 -0.702 ]
 [ 0.2672 -0.5912  0.3773  1.8541  0.8134]
 [-0.8145 -0.4732  0.1427  0.6185  1.    ]]
```

added code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from scipy.fft import fft2, fftshift, ifft2
import numpy as np


nb_channels = 1
h, w = 5, 5
x =     [[[[ 0.6908,  1.2291, -0.7020,  1.0186, -1.2585],
          [ 0.3773,  1.8541,  0.8134,  0.2672, -0.5912],
          [ 0.1427,  0.6185,    1.000, -0.8145, -0.4732],
          [ 1.9047, -0.0119,  0.8849, -1.2321, -0.5614],
          [ 0.0910,  1.0923, -0.6255, -1.9881,  1.9961]]]]
x = torch.tensor(x)
x = x.view(1, nb_channels, h, w)
weights1 = torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
                        [0., 1., 0.],
                        [0., 0., 0.]])

weights = weights1.view(1, 1, 3, 3).repeat(1, nb_channels, 1, 1)

output = F.conv2d(x, weights, padding='same')
print("conv:", output)


################### FT numpy
a = x.numpy()
mac = a.copy()
img = np.squeeze(mac)

fft_in1 = fft2(img)

w_numpy = weights1.numpy()
weights_numpy = w_numpy.copy()
pad_weights = np.pad(weights_numpy, ((1, 1), (1, 1)), mode='constant', constant_values=(0, 0))

fft_weights = fft2(pad_weights)
pad_weights = fft_weights

out1 = fft_in1 * pad_weights
output_n = out1

output_numpy = ifft2(output_n)
output_numpy = output_numpy.real
output_numpy = np.around(output_numpy, decimals = 4)

print("after IFFT:", output_numpy)
```

Comment: have you tried anything? hard to comment on *your* implementation without seeing it

Comment: Yes, I tried flipping the kernel matrix from left to right, then up to down. I tried transposing it. I tried using np.conjugate(). I tried all this ops also, only on the input or on both, the input and the kernel.